# Parsing XML document in PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, encoding, simplexml

I have an XML file which I'm parsing with SimpleXML in php. The first line is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

The result of the parse is stored in `$xml`, if I do:

```
echo $xml->asXML();
```

then the entire file displays perfectly.

But if I dig into the structure in anyway, I get Â's everwhere, eg:

```
echo $xml->Chapter->asXML();
```

Inside some of the XML elements there is MathML (`<math>`), this is where the Â's occur.
For example the character `∈` is replaced by a Â.

How can I parse the XML file but not lose the MathML characters?

Comment: ∈ is not a character that can be represented in ISO 8859-1, change your XML to say that it is encoded with UTF-8. You will also need to tell PHP that its output is UTF-8.

Comment: but its represented fine if I just view the xml file itself in the browser, and also as I said above the Âs only appear after digging into the structure.

Comment: Then PHP is already outputting as UTF-8, you'll still need to change the `encoding="…"` in the XML.

Comment: changing `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>` to `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` makes no difference.

Comment: Is your page being output as UTF-8? Is the input XML really ISO 8859-1?

Comment: This is the XML file: http://mathcanvas.net16.net/cds/fp1_ch1.xml  this is the PHP source: http://pastebin.com/VXr7Prns here is the actual php file: http://mathcanvas.net16.net/cds/answer.php

Comment: I tried what you posted in your answer and got Â^^ outputted both times.

Comment: @YzmirRamirez, the file is in "us-ascii". Why is the encoding mentioned in the xml file different to the actual encoding?

Comment: Looks like the file is UTF-8 based on the encoding of the file.  Perhaps your browser isn't supporting MathML?

Comment: I don't see Â anywhere, could you point it out?

Comment: Make sure your PHP is outputting UTF-8 and your sample XML file works fine for me. http://codepad.viper-7.com/RM9caw

Comment: @salathe, thanks :) , if you put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Browser support for MathML - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML#Web_browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

∈ is not a character that can be represented in ISO 8859-1, change your XML to say that it is encoded with UTF-8.

To give an example demonstrating the problem.

```
$x = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<example><math>∈</math></example>');
echo $x->math, PHP_EOL;

$x = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<example><math>∈</math></example>');
echo $x->math, PHP_EOL;
```

Outputs (as UTF-8) the following.

```
â
∈
```

---

SimpleXML will try to convert to UTF-8 when the `encoding` is set to something different. It is always a good idea not to give it that work to do when the input is already UTF-8 encoded and the `encoding` declaration is incorrect.

---

Also be sure that PHP itself is outputting UTF-8, and telling the browser that this is the case!

You can do this by setting the `default_charset` INI option (in your php.ini or with `ini_set()`), or sending the correct `Content-Type` header (`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8')`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not your encoding, the problem is that not all browsers support [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML) that your [script](http://mathcanvas.net16.net/cds/answer.php) is echoing to the browser.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML#Web_browsers

Tested this in the following browser:

- Safari 5.1.2 - failed
- Chrome 17.0.9x - partial
- Firefox 3.6.28 - works

Comment: No this is not the problem, as MathML works in Safari 5.1.4 elsewhere.

Comment: I respectfully disagree.  If you open your script in the different browsers you'll see that each renders the output of your script differently.

Comment: Yes I know, it will be different in each browser, but loading the XML file as it is in Safari 5.1.4 (and Firefox), shows the MathML as expected (without the Â). So this is not the problem

Answer (score -1):

You may need to convert the input into other encoding before parsing it with SimpleXML.

1. Read file contents as text
2. Convert to different encoding
3. Parse with SimpleXML and do whatever you want
4. If needed, convert the output to original encoding

For this, function iconv() is very useful:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php